# how to count number of exceptions in unit test java?

Tags: java, unit-testing

In the code, I count number of exceptions. In the unit test, it seems that i cant assertEquals for expected number of exceptions because it throw exception in the test before the assertEquals. How can i do it?

Comment: How are you doing the unit test? Are you using JUnit? Please clarify. Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to count the number of exceptions? Wouldn't you be handling the exception once the very first one is caught?

Answer (score 0):

Java `Exception` handle in a such a way that once in `Execution` order if an `Exception` occurs, it will bypass rest of the code in `try` statement and directly jump into `Catch` statement, `final` statement and then run the code after that. So the code in between first time `Exception` occurred and the end of `try` statement will be skipped.

Even thought this is very sloppy method i suggest you to keep every method in unique `try-catch` statement for each . So you can count all the exceptions occurred in the code.